# How to merge matchingCols without listing all column names when using full join in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

In the example below, can I combine column `id` and `t2_id` into one column with full join? I only wanted to have three columns. Some of the values will be empty, but the id column should be fully filled. Also, how do I get rid of some of the column names in the table?

| id | value | t2_id | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7.8 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 4.6 |  |  |
| 3 | 5.1 | 3 | 500 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 3 | 500 |
|  |  | 5 | 300 |

Answer (score 0):

You can drop extra columns with function `dropColumns!`. This way, you don't need to list all the columns' names. You can refer to the example below:

```
t1=table(1 2 3 3 as id, 7.8 4.6 5.1 0.1 as value);
t2=table(5 3 1 as id, 300 500 800 as qty);
a=(select iif(id = NULL, t2.id, id) as id, * from fj(t1, t2, `id)).dropColumns!(`t2_id`t1_id)
```